# Finding volume using triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of solid bounded by the $x^2+y^2=a^2$ , $y^2 + z^2 =a^2$ , $x^2 + z^2 = a^2$

I can see that shadow in $x$y region is given by $x^2 + y^2 =a^2$ . but when I draw ray from shadow to up to both of cylinders hot do I know which cylinder it vl hit ie the $yz$ plane or $xz$ plane cylinder .

Comment: here is an answer [https://math.la.asu.edu/~nbrewer/Spring2008/MAT267/Footnote18/David%20Hilgers/DavidHilgers.html]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating volume enclosed using triple integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923508/calculating-volume-enclosed-using-triple-integral)

Comment: @ Semsem ; that link is not working .wen i click o it it says 404 not found

Comment: @EulerRamanujan121: Just remove the trailing "]" from the URL: https://math.la.asu.edu/~nbrewer/Spring2008/MAT267/Footnote18/David%20Hilgers/DavidHilgers.html .

Comment: pls see if u can help me other problem of surface integral

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964741/finding-surface-integral-need-help?noredirect=1#comment1981807_964741

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966785/finding-distinct-no-of-basis-linear-algebra